# Shadowing declaration does not produce any warnings

Tags: c, gcc

`gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`

I have a library dev package installed on my system with headers that I use to compile my binary. The external declarations of one of the header files looks as

`test.h`:

```
#ifndef AAA
#define AAA

typedef struct test test;

#endif
```

My binary is

`main.c`

```
#include <lib/test.h>

int main(void){
    test *test = NULL; //no warning produced
    (void) test;
}
```

When compiling with `-Wshadow` no warning is produced. However if I include a hand-written file with the same declaration as

`mytest.h`:

```
#ifndef AAA
#define AAA

typedef struct test test;

#endif
```

`main.c`

```
#include "mytest.h"

int main(void){
    //warning: declaration of ‘test’ shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]
    test *test = NULL; 
    (void) test;
}
```

Is that an expected behavior? I was thinking that the warning would be printed in both of the cases

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. There is no global called `test` anywhere.

Comment: You mean you think the warning is not generated in the first case because of the angle-bracket inclusion? I can't reproduce that behavior. I get a `-Wshadow` warning in both cases. What version of gcc are you on?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The `test` is a `typedef struct test test` included from headers

Comment: @PSkocik I use `gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`. What version did you try?

Comment: `gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-6ubuntu1~18.04~ppa1)`.

Comment: @PSkocik I updated `gcc`  to `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0` and still don't get the warning...

Comment: @St.Anario I had originally tested with the header in a user location (added to the angle-bracket header path with `<>`). Moving it to `/usr/include/lib/` hid the warning as in your case. Rest in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headers in system locations have warnings disabled unless you pass `-Wsystem-headers`.

With `-Wsystem-headers -Wshadow`, you should get that warning even if the file is in `/usr/include`.

The option is documented in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options:

> -Wsystem-headers
>
> Print warning messages for constructs found in system header files. Warnings from system headers are normally suppressed, on
>   the assumption that they usually do not indicate real problems and
>   would only make the compiler output harder to read. Using this
>   command-line option tells GCC to emit warnings from system headers as
>   if they occurred in user code. However, note that using -Wall in
>   conjunction with this option does not warn about unknown pragmas in
>   system headers—for that, -Wunknown-pragmas must also be used.

Empirically `-Wsystem-headers` causes the warning to reappear, but the behavior could be considered a gcc bug since the overshadowing happens in user code, not the system header where the overshadowed global originates.

Comment: But the OP expects a warning for the code *in his own source file*, not in a system header.  `-Wsystem-headers` is (supposed to be) about generating warnings for code found in the headers themselves.  It is sensible because it is reasonable to assume the code in such headers to be correct, and because it is outside ordinary users' ability to change anyway.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'd call it a gcc bug that the `-Wshadow` problem in user code doesn't generate a warning iff the symbol originates in a system header, but empirically, `-Wsystem-headers` fixes the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is not a file included with `< >` treated as system headers? Actually inclusion with `" "` does not fix the problem unless `-Wsystem-headers` is specified.

Comment: @St.Antario, whether it is a system header is not directly related to the form of `#include` directive you use, but that's wholly beside the point.  I'm not suggesting that the header in question should not be considered a system header.  I'm saying that the header is not the location of the code you want to be warned about, and `-Wsystem-headers` is supposed to modulate only warnings arising from code ***in** system headers*.  That's different from "related to system headers", which is your case.